# Button и RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Вообщем, суть такова. У меня есть список RecyclerView, который состоит из 10 блоков. Каждый блок выводит одну и ту же кнопку, которую я задал в адаптере. Проблема вот в чем: Вот например у меня есть десять ссылок, и мне нужно к каждой кнопке, которая выводится в RecyclerView, задать свою ссылку. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать такой момент? Как идентифицировать эти кнопки с recyclerView? или получить их позицию и как-то с ними манипулировать? Не до конца понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все довольно просто. В конструктор адаптера при создании списка кроме того что вы передаете какую-то информацию для отображения (текст, картинки и т.п.) вам нужно передавать массив с ссылками. Сам массив вы заполняете ссылками для каждого элемента списка и в самом адаптере при нажатии на кнопку вытаскиваете данные из массива. В адаптере есть такая функция `onBindViewHolder()` где вы заполняете элементы списка данными которые пришли в адаптер, там вы будете извлекать ссылку согласно позиции элемента списка. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786796/how-to-display-an-arraylist-in-a-recyclerview) например вопрос по вашей проблеме. Не обязательно отображать данные из массива ссылок, просто в нужный момент вы сможете извлекать оттуда данные.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.вот то что нужно

Comment: да.сейчас.просто две минуты не разрешал сайт отметить